# Testing fetch request with Jest and Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I started learning to test React applications, now I want to test fetch request, I succeeded, seems like it works, but what's the proper way to do it, here is my try:

```
const fetchSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch')
        .mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
            json: () => ([{ id: 0, title: "Title", body: "Body", userId: 1 }]),
        }));

    let wrapper = await shallow(<Posts />);

    expect(fetchSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

    setTimeout(async () => {
        await wrapper.update()
        expect(wrapper.state('posts').length).toEqual(1)
    })
```

And also, what would be better way to wait for component to update instead setTimeout ?

Answer (score 1):

Not only `setTimeout` helps but `Promise.resolve()` also puts some code in the end of queue. Since with `Promise` we can use `await` and let Jest know we are doing something async it could be more clear:

```
test('testing something', async () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(<Posts />); 
    await Promise.resolve(); 
    /* everything below is put in the end of the queue 
     - so after mocked fetch() has resolved and response processed */
    expect(fetchSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // wrapper.update(); // it is not required
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Your `await shallow(...)` does the same: puts everything below in the end of queue(like if it was `Promise.resolve(shallow(<Posts />)).then(<code below>)`). But I believe `await Promise.resolve()` is less confusing because looks(surprise!) really untypical :) So nobody might think you are (incorrectly) relying on `shallow()` returns Promise(and it does not).

Jest [does not have feature](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2157) like "flush promises". `.runAllTimers()` works only with `setTimeout`/`setInterval` and actually does not make them sync but rather speed-up them(and they still are async).

[UPD] you even don't need `wrapper.update()` if you wait somehow till all async tasks are done. At least it works fine for me at codesandbox.io without `wrapper.update()`